# Error 500 after composer update in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, composer-php

i try to clone my project into my computer. 
I had clone the repository and done "composer update". All without any errors.

when i try to visit my site show this error

```
Call to a member function has() on null
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError
```

and the debug

```
CRITICAL - Call to a member function has() on null 
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function has() on null" at C:\xampp\htdocs\richiesta_analisi\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 234
```

is the same repository that i had in remote so i don't understand why don't work.
i tryed to clear cache and composer upgrade but nothing.

Can you help me?

Comment: Verify if the `vendors` folder has the respective dependencies inside.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063848/call-to-a-member-function-has-on-null-500-with-symfony-and-doctrine

Comment: there is no `234` line in my SF3.4 -
 FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php

Comment: flag 
Verify if the vendors folder has the respective dependencies inside    how?

Comment: the 234 line is 
     protected function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        if ($this->container->has('templating')) {
            return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($view, $parameters, $response);
        }

Comment: i manually copy folder vendor and it work but why it can be?

Comment: Did you cleaned the cache directory ? Sometimes doing it manualy helps : `rm -r var/cache/{dev,prod}`.

Comment: you should clean cache and you should remove it from your git repository.